# Why is an open disk not open when thought of as a subset of a plane in $E^3$?

Tags: differential-geometry

An open disk is open in $E^3$. I believe this makes sense since the boundary of the open disk is not included with the set of interior points.

However, apparently, an open disk is not open when considered as a subset of a plane in $E^3$. Why is that? What does it even mean to be "thought of" as a subset of a plane in $E^3$?

Comment: open disk is an open subset of $E^2$, not of $E^3$. A ball drawn at a point of the disk always contains nonmember points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $D=\{\langle x,y,0\rangle\in\Bbb R^3:x^2+y^2<1\}$; this is the open disk in $\Bbb R^2$ in its most natural embedding in $\Bbb R^3$. It’s an open subset of the subspace $\{\langle x,y,z\rangle\in\Bbb R^3:z=0\}$, the $xy$-plane in $\Bbb R^3$, but it’s not an open subset of $\Bbb R^3$: no matter how small a positive $\epsilon$ you choose, the open ball

$$\{\langle x,y,z\rangle\in\Bbb R^3:x^2+y^2+z^2<\epsilon^2\}$$

of radius $\epsilon$ centred at the origin is not a subset of $D$. Open balls in $\Bbb R^3$ all have positive volume and an extension in all three dimensions, and $D$ does not.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a set $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open if for every $x \in U$, there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B(x, \epsilon) \subseteq U$, where $B(x, \epsilon)$ is the open all of radius $\epsilon$. Given any point on the $2$-dimensional open disk $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$, any open ball (in $\mathbb{R}^3$) around the point cannot be contained in $D$, so $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ is not open.  It's pretty much the same reason why the real line is not open in $\mathbb{R}^2$.